# How to create a helm chart to deploy multiple applications using the same value.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy
an HTTPD instance and a couch db instance using the same `values.yaml` file

Is there a default document that can help me understand how to deploy two instances and there services using the same `values.yaml` file?

Anyone with a sample helm directory with multiple deployments and services created?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to put both services into one helm chart. So they will use only one same `values.yaml`.

As a sample, I suggest you to look to [`stable/prometheus` helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus). Right now it has five separated services:

```
$ tree 
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── README.md
├── templates
│   ├── alertmanager-clusterrolebinding.yaml
│   ├── alertmanager-configmap.yaml
│   ├── alertmanager-deployment.yaml
│   ├── alertmanager-ingress.yaml
│   ├── alertmanager-networkpolicy.yaml
│   ├── alertmanager-pvc.yaml
│   ├── alertmanager-serviceaccount.yaml
│   ├── alertmanager-service.yaml
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── kube-state-metrics-clusterrolebinding.yaml
│   ├── kube-state-metrics-clusterrole.yaml
│   ├── kube-state-metrics-deployment.yaml
│   ├── kube-state-metrics-networkpolicy.yaml
│   ├── kube-state-metrics-serviceaccount.yaml
│   ├── kube-state-metrics-svc.yaml
│   ├── node-exporter-clusterrolebinding.yaml
│   ├── node-exporter-daemonset.yaml
│   ├── node-exporter-serviceaccount.yaml
│   ├── node-exporter-service.yaml
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── pushgateway-deployment.yaml
│   ├── pushgateway-ingress.yaml
│   ├── pushgateway-service.yaml
│   ├── server-clusterrolebinding.yaml
│   ├── server-clusterrole.yaml
│   ├── server-configmap.yaml
│   ├── server-deployment.yaml
│   ├── server-ingress.yaml
│   ├── server-networkpolicy.yaml
│   ├── server-pvc.yaml
│   ├── server-serviceaccount.yaml
│   └── server-service.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Comment: Does anyone know a more digestable (read - smaller) example that illustrates configuring multiple services/deployments with a single Helm Chart?

Comment: Prometheus community has given up on this structure. Have a look at https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts for better examples.

Comment: nice talk with codes!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the following command to deploy both applications separately with one `values.yaml` file:

```
helm install -f my-values.yaml chart1
helm install -f my-values.yaml chart2
```

Comment: Do you have a sample that i could refer